# Multiple text search in Qradar AQL

Tags: arrays, search, text, aql

how can i search multiple text in Qradar AQL? the IN function works only for IP address. I want to search like below, any alternate options?

> WHERE URL NOT ILIKE IN ('%.com%', '%.net%')

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow syntax:

```
select URL FROM events WHERE URL IS NOT NULL and  URL NOT ILIKE ENUMERATION('%.com%')
```

For more information please refer following guide:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS42VS_7.3.2/com.ibm.qradar.doc/b_qradar_aql.pdf